# How to get error message when ifstream open fails

Tags: c++, error-handling, stream, std

```
ifstream f;
f.open(fileName);

if ( f.fail() )
{
    // I need error message here, like "File not found" etc. -
    // the reason of the failure
}
```

How to get error message as string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ ifstream Error Checking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446593/c-ifstream-error-checking)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you get a specific error condition when a C++ stream open fails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303966/can-you-get-a-specific-error-condition-when-a-c-stream-open-fails)

Comment: @Alex Farber: Sure. `cerr << "Error code: " << strerror(errno); // Get some info as to why` seems relevant to the question.

Comment: @MatthieuRouget: Check the possible duplicate I posted -- it seems this is non-standard behaviour only implemented by gcc.

Comment: @MatthieuRouget: `strerror(errno)` works. Post this as answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Every system call that fails update the `errno` value.

Thus, you can have more information about what happens when a `ifstream` open fails by using something like :

```
cerr << "Error: " << strerror(errno);
```

---

<s>However, since *every* system call updates the global `errno` value, you may have issues in a multithreaded application, if another system call triggers an error between the execution of the `f.open` and use of `errno`.</s>

**On system with POSIX standard:**

> errno is thread-local; setting it in one thread does not affect its
>   value in any other thread.

---

**Edit** (thanks to Arne Mertz and other people in the comments):

`e.what()` seemed at first to be a more C++-idiomatically correct way of implementing this, however the string returned by this function is implementation-dependant and (at least in G++'s libstdc++) this string has no useful information about the reason behind the error...

Comment: `e.what()` does not seem to give much information, see updates to my answer.

Comment: `errno` uses thread-local storage on modern operating systems. However, there's no guarantee that the `fstream` functions will not clobber `errno` after an errno occurs. The underlying functions may not set `errno` at all (direct system calls on Linux, or Win32). This doesn't work on many real world implementations.

Comment: In MSVC, `e.what()` always prints the same message "`iostream stream error`"

Comment: `warning C4996: 'strerror': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strerror_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\string.h(168) : see declaration of 'strerror'`

Comment: @sergiol Those are lies. Ignore them or disable the warning.

Answer (score 42):

You could try letting the stream throw an exception on failure:

```
std::ifstream f;
//prepare f to throw if failbit gets set
std::ios_base::iostate exceptionMask = f.exceptions() | std::ios::failbit;
f.exceptions(exceptionMask);

try {
  f.open(fileName);
}
catch (std::ios_base::failure& e) {
  std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
}
```

`e.what()`, however, does not seem to be very helpful:

- I tried it on Win7, Embarcadero RAD Studio 2010 where it gives "ios_base::failbit set" whereas `strerror(errno)` gives "No such file or directory."
- On Ubuntu 13.04, gcc 4.7.3 the exception says "basic_ios::clear" (thanks to [arne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/818924/arne))

If `e.what()` does not work for you (I don't know what it will tell you about the error, since that's not standardized), try using `std::make_error_condition` (C++11 only):

```
catch (std::ios_base::failure& e) {
  if ( e.code() == std::make_error_condition(std::io_errc::stream) )
    std::cerr << "Stream error!\n"; 
  else
    std::cerr << "Unknown failure opening file.\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't test this because `strerror(errno)` posted in the comments works and very simple for using. I think that `e.what` will work, since `errno` works.

Comment: Then see the annotaions about multithreading in Matthieus answer - my guess is that `e.what()` will be what `strerror` returns, in a threadsafe way. Both will probably platform dependent.

Comment: @AlexFarber: I think that Arne's answer is better than mine. My solution is not the _C++-way_ of solving your issue. However, I did not find official information about how the C++ library maps system call errors to `exception.what()`. May be a good opportunity to dive into the libstdc++ source code :-)

Comment: I tried this out: Tried to open a nonexisting file and the exception message read `basic_ios::clear`, nothing else. This isn't really helpful. That's why I didn't post ;)

Comment: @arne wich platform, compiler, os?

Comment: @MatthieuRouget see my update to the answer - I'd prefer strerror on the platform I am using. (though I would prefer using another compiler, tbh)

Comment: @ArneMertz: amd64, gcc version 4.7.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1), Lubuntu 13.04 with all recent updated installed.

Comment: @All: OK interesting. Sadly, while my answer seems to be the good one, it looks very "old school". Updated my answer. As a side note, I saw nothing else than static strings in the call of `ios_base::failure`'s constructor in the libstdc++ source code.... (i.e. no reference to somthing that looks like `errno`)

Comment: This will also throw an exception on successful opening of the file in c++ 20.

Answer (score 30):

Following on @Arne Mertz's answer, as of C++11 `std::ios_base::failure` inherits from `system_error` (see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/failure/), which contains both the error code and message that `strerror(errno)` would return.

```
std::ifstream f;

// Set exceptions to be thrown on failure
f.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);

try {
    f.open(fileName);
} catch (std::system_error& e) {
    std::cerr << e.code().message() << std::endl;
}
```

This prints `No such file or directory.` if `fileName` doesn't exist.

Comment: For me in MSVC 2015 that just prints `iostream stream error`.

Comment: For me GCC 6.3 also prints `iostream error`. What compiler did you test this on? Does any compiler actually provide a user-readable reason for failure?

Comment: Clang 6 on libc++ on macOS: `unspecified iostream_category error`.

Comment: Xcode 10.2.1 (Clang) / libc++ (C++17) on MacOS 10.14.x: also "Unspecified iostream_category error".  strerror(errno) SEEMS to be the only way to get this right.  I suppose I could catch it first by asking std::filesystem if the path.exists(), and examining the std::error_code it returns.

Comment: In the example program, the statement `f.open(fileName)` throws an exception of type `std::ios_base::failure`, which is derived from `std::system_error`.  The exception is caught by the catch block. Within the catch block, `e.code()` invokes `std::ios_base::failure::code()` which returns an object of type `std::error_code`.  The error codes defined by class `std::error_code` are ***platform-dependent***--i.e., `e.code().message()` and `e.code().value()` both return platform-dependent values.

Answer (score 18):

You can also throw a `std::system_error` as shown in the test code below.  This method seems to produce more readable output than `f.exception(...)`.

```
#include <exception> // <-- requires this
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

void process(const std::string& fileName) {
    std::ifstream f;
    f.open(fileName);

    // after open, check f and throw std::system_error with the errno
    if (!f)
        throw std::system_error(errno, std::system_category(), "failed to open "+fileName);

    std::clog << "opened " << fileName << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    try {
        process(argv[1]);
    } catch (const std::system_error& e) {
        std::clog << e.what() << " (" << e.code() << ")" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Example output (Ubuntu w/clang):

```
$ ./test /root/.profile
failed to open /root/.profile: Permission denied (system:13)
$ ./test missing.txt
failed to open missing.txt: No such file or directory (system:2)
$ ./test ./test
opened ./test
$ ./test $(printf '%0999x')
failed to open 000...000: File name too long (system:36)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `std::system_error` example above is slightly incorrect. `std::system_category()` will map the error codes from system's native error code facility. For *nix, this is `errno`. For Win32, it is `GetLastError()`. ie, on Windows, the above example will print

```
failed to open C:\path\to\forbidden: The data is invalid
```

because EACCES is 13 which is the Win32 error code ERROR_INVALID_DATA

To fix it, either use the system's native error code facility, eg on Win32

```
throw new std::system_error(GetLastError(), std::system_category(), "failed to open"+ filename);
```

Or use errno and `std::generic_category()`, eg

```
throw new std::system_error(errno, std::generic_category(), "failed to open"+ filename);
```

Comment: Note that you shouldn't throw raw pointers unless your framework requires you to. Use `throw std::make_shared<std::system_error>(...)`, or even better, `throw std::system_error(...)`.