# How to make ifstream follow symbolic link?

Tags: linux, symlink, c++

In my C++ program I'm using `ifstream("/etc/mtab", ios::ate|ios:in)`. An year back the program ran good but now `ifstream::is_open()` is returning false. By digging I found `/etc/mtab` is a symbolic link to `/proc/mounts`

--Update--

`/proc/mounts` is again a symbolic link to `/proc/self/mounts` which is actual file. I couldn't succeed opening this thought I'm running the program as a root user. So may be ifstream is following the symbolic link and is not able to open `/proc/self/mounts`

Comment: Can you `cat` (or `hexdump` or `md5sum` or whatever) the file?

Comment: What error does it report? http://stackoverflow.com/a/17338934/1116364

Comment: @5gon12eder I cat the file as a normal user

Comment: @DanielJour ifstream::is_open() is returning false.

Comment: But what error does it report? Please follow the link I provided!

Comment: @DanielJour `strerror(errno)` returned `success`!

Comment: Can you post the output of running `stat` on all involved symlinks and files as well as a minimal code example that exhibits that behavior on your setup? Oh, and also check what `stream.good()` returns! Also check if you didnt accidentally move from the stream (did you switch to C++11)

Answer (score 1):

although not directly answering on how to resolve symbolic links with `std::fstream`, a filesystem library was [introduced by C++ 17](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/17) (was not available at the time this question was opened)

it can deal with symlinks by:

- resolving symlinks: [`std::filesystem::read_symlink`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/read_symlink)
- copy symlinks: [`std::filesystem::copy_symlink`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy_symlink)
- create symlinks: [`std::filesystem::create_symlink`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_symlink)
- test for symlink: [`std::filesystem::is_symlink`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/is_symlink)

note that a filesystem library is also [available in boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html)