# In C++ std:: streams, after a failure, how to get a failure reason? Required: threadsafe and common to Windows and Linux (or at least Msvc/Gcc)

Tags: c++, c++11, error-handling, stream, iostream

Sorry for weird title. Limited to 150 chars so couldn't use proper sentences.

So let's say I've done the following to find out that something went wrong with my file stream:

```
std::ofstream ofs;
do_stuff_with(ofs);
// streams don't throw on error because C++ [edit: we can make them do so, but the .what()s aren't very user-friendly]
// so we have to check for failure manually
if(!ofs){
    auto fail_code = errno; // threadsafe on Win/Linux
    // but what goes here?
}
```

1) strerror:
Not threadsafe

2) strerror_s: Not in GCC? Or is it?

3) strerror_r: Not in Msvc? Or is it?

4) #ifdef/#define/etc: yuck, but may be the only choice

I did do some searching but I didn't find a "this will definitely work in a sensible yet slightly platform-dependent way" answer... That said, I feel like this is "obviously a duplicate question", but I can't find the original...

Comment: You can make stream throw on error if you want.

Comment: The closest you can get in c++ is [`std::io_errc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/io_errc)

Comment: ["`// streams don't throw on error because C++`"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions). Not that it is guaranteed to have a useful `what()`.

Comment: Ah I knew about the exceptions() thing, but for some reason I had the idea that it wasn't properly implemented either. But it seems to work, just it gives messages like "ios_base::failbit set" rather than "No such file or directory." as discovered elsewhere on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17337602/how-to-get-error-message-when-ifstream-open-fails

Comment: check out `throw`, `what()`, `try` and `catch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always throw your own exceptions using `std::system_error`:

```
#include <cerrno>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <system_error>

int main()
{
    try
    {
        std::ofstream foo{"/root/bar.baz"};
        foo << "bla" << std::endl;
        foo.close();

        if(!foo)
            throw std::system_error{errno, std::generic_category()};
    }
    catch(const std::system_error& err)
    {
         std::cout << "Error: " << err.code() << " - " << err.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This returns `Error: generic:13 - Permission denied`.

Comment: I think std::system_error may be what I've been looking for! I'll try this and then mark this as the answer if it turns out to satisfy my requirements.

Comment: I edited in a snippet for getting the error message without going via an exception, too, since one of my main issues was getting a readable message out (rather than throwing exceptions, though that's also useful).

Answer (score 1):

Since C++11, you can use the class `std::error_code` for that:

```
std::cout << std::error_code{errno, std::generic_category()}.message();
```

In fact you can even do it a little shorter than that:

```
std::cout << std::generic_category().message(errno);
```

Though I must say I find the first one a little more idiomatic.

As a sidenote, there is also `std::system_category()`, which seems to be largely equivalent to `generic_category()` on Unix but on Windows, it can be used to translate Windows API error codes such as returned by `GetLastError()` etc.

This is the same class that's also used within the `std::system_error` exception, but you don't need to create an instance of the exception if all you want to do is to get the error message.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could come up with. It's the "yuck" answer, but at least you can put the "yuck" in a single function and hide it away in some cpp file somewhere. std::ios covers boost streams as well, of course.

Requires #ifdefs so it's a cheat. I believe Visual Studio #defines _WIN32 by default, so at least you don't have to set up that infrastructure per se.

```
void check_stream(std::ios & stream)
{
    if (!stream){
        char err[1024] = { 0 };
#ifdef _WIN32
        strerror_s(err, errno);
#else
        strerror_r(errno, err, 1024);
#endif
        throw MyException(err);
    }
}
```

My own solution makes me sad so hopefully a better one will come along. But time is finite, so just submit to the Dark Side, use something like this, and get on with your life. :P

```
try{
    boost::filesystem::ifstream ifs("testfile");
    check_stream(ifs);
}
catch (std::exception & e){
    std::cout << e.what(); // "No such file or directory"
}
```