# Cannot read input file using ifstream c++

Tags: c++, ifstream

I have an input file "abc.txt" which contains characters seperated by ',' in every line.
While trying to read the file line by line using ifstream, its unable to read the file and I am getting the output on console as "Cannot open input file.".
What am I doing wrong?
The code:-

```
void EnterFiles(string filename, int index)
{
    string line;
    vector<string> f1,f2;

    std::ifstream f;

    //prepare f to throw if failbit gets set

    std::ios_base::iostate exceptionMask = f.exceptions() | std::ios::failbit;
    f.exceptions(exceptionMask);
    try
    {
        f.open(filename);
    }
    catch (std::ios_base::failure& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
    }
    if (!f)
    {
        cout << "Cannot open input file.\n";
    }
    while (getline(f,line) )
    {   
        if (index == 0)
        {
            f1.push_back(line);
            cout << line << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            f2.push_back(line);
            cout << line << endl;
        }
    }
    f.close();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Use the full path name for the file.

Comment: You didn't gave your file-path, Is your file in the same directory with you program? If not, you mus give it the correct path.

Comment: You should try to print the cause: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17337602/how-to-get-error-message-when-ifstream-open-fails

Comment: With that path you need to run the program from the same directory as the file. How are you running your program?

Comment: Hey all . abc.txt file is in the same directory as my exe. Still I get the error

Comment: Hey @GauravKumar, just move abc.txt to folder which has exe.

Comment: The folder containing the exe is not necessarily the *current working directory*.

Comment: **How are you running your program?**

Comment: sorry guys. Found out the issue. Silly one indeed. In windows , .txt is added as an extension by default and the name of the file which I provided was abc.txt. Thus file was abc.txt.txt. Corrected the same. Bummer it was . Apologise for inconvenience if any!

Answer (score 0):

If condition is satisfied every time, thus skipping else part.

provide full or qualified file path (Sometimes it creates problem !!),
Also, include  file (if not !!).

Following is an examples similar to your code, which you refer, 
(It is checked by me works like a charm in Linux)

http://cpp-tutorial.cpp4u.com/STL_ifstream.html

Hope, this answer might be of help.

Comment: while trying the following:-