# trying to write structure to file but keep getting error finding file

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I attempted to create a program that opens a file called "hours1.txt" which reads all the data from this file storing it into a vector. Then it should output all the data to a file called "payments1.txt". Although, I cant even get the file to open I dont know what im doing wrong.

```
using namespace std;

struct PayRecords{

    char lastName[50];
    char firstName[50]; 
    double hW; 
    double hoW;
};

int main()
{
    vector<PayRecords>payInfo; // creating an empty vector that will hold the data..

    PayRecords data; // creating an object that can access each member of the structure..

    ifstream infile; // declaring an object that can open the file..
    infile.open("hours1.txt");  // opening the file..

    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("payments1.txt"); 

    if(!infile) 
    {
        cerr << "Sorry this file could not be opened! Maybe its not placed in the right folder???" << endl; 
        return 1; 
    }


    while(infile >> data.lastName >> data.firstName >> data.hW >> data.hoW) // while we arent at the end of the file, keep reading each piece of new data.. 
    {
        payInfo.push_back(data); // adding the data to each member of the structure into the vector..
    }


    for(int i=0; i<payInfo.size(); i++) // this for loop is displaying all the results 
    {
        outfile << "YOUR NAME" << endl; 
        outfile << "PAY FOR THIS WEEK" << endl; 
        outfile << "==========================" << endl << endl; 
        outfile << payInfo[i].lastName << endl; 
        outfile << payInfo[i].firstName << endl; 
        outfile << payInfo[i].hW << endl; 
        outfile << payInfo[i].hoW << endl; 
    }

    cout << payInfo.size(); 
    infile.close();
    outfile.close(); 

    cout << "thank you the file has been changed"; 
}
```

Comment: What happens when you use the full path? Make sure to escape backslashes like `"C:\\somedirectory\\afile.txt"`. Are you sure the file is in the right directory?

Comment: You should use `std::string` instead of char arrays. It will make your life much easier.

Comment: *Although, I cant even get the file to open* -- If that's the problem, why all this code that has nothing to do with the problem?  A simple 2 or 3 line `main` function attempting to open a file is all that's necessary.

Comment: Use the information at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17337602/how-to-get-error-message-when-ifstream-open-fails to check why your Open call is failing.  Don't just shoot in the dark.

Comment: place hours1.txt in the directory where the program is running from.