# ifstream not reading anything

Tags: c++, cmake, ifstream

I'm writing code in C++ and I need to read a file, problem is my file structure is a bit complex and I just cannot figure out how to use my ifstream to read it. I think I tried all possible combinations... but it just doesn't work, I guess I'm doing something wrong but I can't figure it out.

Here is a minimal reproduction of my problem.

structure :

```
.
├── build
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── src
    ├── file
    │   └── test.txt
    ├── load
    │   └── loadfile.hpp
    └── main.cpp
```

CMakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(BaseProject)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O3 -g -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic")

file(GLOB SRC
        "src/*.h"
        "src/*.hpp"
        "src/load/*.h"
        "src/load/*.hpp"
        "src/load/*.cpp"
        )

add_executable(exec ${SRC} src/main.cpp)
```

main.cpp

```
#include "load/loadfile.hpp"

int main(){
    load();
    return 0;
}
```

test.txt : (not very relevent but meh)

```
test
```

loadfile.hpp

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void loadFile(const std::string& file){
    std::ifstream i(file, std::ifstream::in);
    std::string str;
    i >> str;
    std::cerr << str;
    i.close();
}

void load(){
    loadFile("../file/test.txt");
}
```

output is empty and program finishes normally.

Comment: Now might be a good time to learn about the concept of *current working directory*. When you run a program, its process will have a *current working directory*. If you run from a console or terminal then it's usually the terminals current directory. Relative paths (paths not beginning with a `/`) are always relative to the current working directory. You need to make sure that the relative path in the program is valid for the programs current working directory when running.

Comment: Also, *always* check for failure when you do something that can fail, like for example opening a file.

Comment: oh... so it's from the build directory if I run the program from here... ok got it ! I thought it was relative to a file or something. Thanks for the help !

Comment: you could make copying the text.txt to build part of the build process. Later when you install it you will also have to put files in the right place

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17337602/how-to-get-error-message-when-ifstream-open-fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from [Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude) in the comments:

> Now might be a good time to learn about the concept of current working
> directory. When you run a program, its process will have a current
> working directory. If you run from a console or terminal then it's
> usually the terminals current directory. Relative paths (paths not
> beginning with a /) are always relative to the current working
> directory. You need to make sure that the relative path in the program
> is valid for the programs current working directory when running.

Answer (score 0):

This might help, when you call install your files will be copied to destination specified.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(BaseProject)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O3 -g -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic")
set(OUTPUT_DIR "Yours to fill, working dir")

file(GLOB RESOURCES "./file/test.txt")

file(GLOB SRC
        "src/*.h"
        "src/*.hpp"
        "src/load/*.h"
        "src/load/*.hpp"
        "src/load/*.cpp"
        )

add_executable(exec ${SRC} src/main.cpp)

install (FILES ${RESOURCES} DESTINATION ${OUTPUT_DIR})
```