# Can't Read file in .exe C++

Tags: c++, csv

this is my first question in Stack Overflow.

I am writing a C++ Program using Xcode and need to read several .csv file in the process. I put the csv files under the root file of my product exe. It works well when I am using the debugger in Xcode and the file can be read. However, when I kick the exe file to start the program, the exe cannot read those csv.

My code are like:

```
ifstream corridor_M;
corridor_M.open("./data/Corridor M.csv");
```

Is there any way to solve this problem so that my .exe can walk  normally like in the debugger?

Comment: Since you're using a relative path, consider the working directory when you run your program.

Comment: The relative path `./` probably indicates a different path when you're on your debugger and not.

Comment: Guess the problem is with the current working directory

Comment: Why don't you check the error condition of the open call? Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303966/can-you-get-a-specific-error-condition-when-a-c-stream-open-fails) and add the error control logic you're missing.

Comment: "./" could mean different path when you execute it with different ways, e.g. click or with xcode.